# Notice: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int in /index.php on line 21

Tags: php, mysqli

me pueden indicar cual es mi error  me pone Notice: Object of class mysqli pero no entiendo porque por favor no lo entiendo les dejo los dos codigos .En la practica que tengo que hacer me pone que en  el archivo sql.php no deberia poner  pero si no no me funciona podria ser ese el error ?

```
<<<index.php>>>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Altas y modificaciones</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    include("sql.php");
    $conexion = conectarse();
    if($conexion == 0){
    echo "<h1> error en la db </h1>";
    exit();
    }
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from my_db");
    ?>
</body>
</html>



<<<sql.php>>>
<?php
function conectarse(){
   $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456789","prueba1");
    return $link;

}
?>
```

Comment: Da la impresión de que ese error ocurre en otra parte. ¿Cuál es la línea 21 de `index.php`? Por otra parte, si la conexión no se realiza, sería `false` por lo que es mejor verificar de este modo: `if(!$conexion){`

Comment: if($conexion == 0){

Comment: Pues ponlo así: `if(!$conexion){`, como dije antes, la función de conexión devuelve `false` cuando no se puede conectar.

Comment: si muchas gracias me funciona (LLLLLLLL)

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect()` devuelve `false` cuando la conexión falla, pero cuando no falla, devuelve un objeto que es la conexión a la base de datos.

Si tú intentas una comparación de este tipo, funcionará cuando la conexión falle:

```
if($conexion == 0){
```

Pero cuando la conexión sea válida PHP intentará convertir `$conexion` a un entero (int) para compararlo con otro valor entero `0` y serás notificado de que no puedes convertir un objeto mysqli a entero: *`Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int`*

Por tanto, la forma correcta para verificar si la conexión es válida es usando el [operador `!` (not)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) en el `if`, de hecho, el [**Ejemplo 1** del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) hace ese tipo de evaluación. Aquí simplemente verificará si `$conexion` es `false`, sin intentar convertir el objeto para hacer la comparación.

```
<?php
    include("sql.php");
    $conexion = conectarse();
    if(!$conexion){
        echo "<h1> error en la db </h1>";
        exit();
    }
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from my_db");
?>
```